# Cannot answer although I could answer normal and protected questions

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

Now I got "Remove New User Restrictions" and have "Create Wiki Posts", "Participate In Meta" and finally "Create Posts". It's nice to collect some trophies.

I'm a new user, but I cannot answer any questions which is sad because I can provide some nice answers. I have no upvotes or downvotes.

So my question is, why is it still disabled/banned? I know that old stuff won't be showed, and I had a time being registered, but I really didn't use SO that much.

I have some time being registered I think and want collaborate a bit more now. So how can I get lifted that ban?

I read the information about answer ban and new user information as well, but I don't get what is wrong.

Comment: Deleted questions and answers still count toward the ban. Since i don't see any questions or answers on your account, I assume you have deleted ones that are contributing to the answer ban.

Comment: You've got 3 deleted answers - the only one that is potentially salvageable is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27141263) - might be worth seeing if you can do anything with that to make it specific to the question asked

Comment: Is there a way to see all the previously posted questions. Sorry, I cannot find where to do that.

Comment: Go to your Profile > Questions. At the bottom of the list there is a link that says, "deleted recent questions".

Comment: It's empty, I guess I cannot see all the older ones.